# Show that questions involving orthonormal basis and inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

The question is:

Show that if $V$ is an inner product space and {$v_1, . . . , v_n$} is an orthonormal basis, then
$v =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \langle v, v_i\rangle v_i$, for all $v ∈ V$ .

To be perfectly honest, I'm unsure of where to begin with this question.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Begin with: $v=\sum_i a_i v_i$ for some $a_i$ since $v_i$ form a basis. Now how would you compute $a_i$?

Comment: Regarding the original version of the question: the Gram-Schmidt process is for constructing an orthonormal basis.  Since we already are given an orthonormal basis, I can't see why constructing one would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every vector $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as: $$v = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}v_{j},$$
once $\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Thus, using the linearity of the inner product, we get, for each $k=1,...,n$:
$$\langle v, v_{k}\rangle = \langle \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}v_{j}, v_{k}\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}\langle v_{j},v_{k}\rangle = \alpha_{k},$$
because $\langle v_{j},v_{k}\rangle = \delta_{jk}$. Thus, for each $k=1,...,n$, $\alpha_{k}=\langle v,v_{k}\rangle$ and:
$$v = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{j}v_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle v, v_{j}\rangle v_{j}$$

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows: it suffices to note that if $\langle v,v_i\rangle = \langle w,v_i \rangle$ for all $i = 1,\dots,n$, then $v$ and $w$ must be the same vector. Apply this fact to $w = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,v_i \rangle v_i$.

Comment: Okay my mistake, I've edited that out of the question now. Thank you for your help.